# Merge sets iteratively if they have more than 50% elements in common

Tags: python, merge, set, reduce

I have a function that given two sets A and B, it returns a marged set A.union(B) if one of the two set shares at least 50% of its elements with the other set, False otherwise:

```
def merged_set_or_false(set1, set2):
  if **magic**:
    return merged_set
  else:
    return False
```

Now, what I would like to do is to iterate through a list of set until no two sets in the list can be merged anymore. What is an efficient way to do it? In my mind it looks like a reduce() but without actually reducing necessarily to a single element.

An example:

```
>>> list_of_sets = [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4,5),(6,7,8,9)]
>>> len(list_of_sets)
3
>>> new_list = merge_until_possible(list_of_sets)
>>> new_list
[(1,2,3,4,5),(6,7,8,9)]
>>> len(new_list)
2
```

Ideas?

**Edit - 4 December 2016**
Just in case anyone could find it useful, this is my current work-in-progress solution for solving this problem:

```
def pseudo_reduce(f, list_to_reduce):
  """Perform f on two elements of list per time until possible."""
  reducing_is_still_possible = True
  exit_loops = False

  while reducing_is_still_possible:
    initial_list_len = len(list_to_reduce)
    for j in range(len(list_to_reduce)):
      # If two elements became one in previous iter, we need to break twice
      if exit_loops:
        exit_loops = False
        break
      # If j is the last element, break to avoid out of index error
      if j == (len(list_to_reduce) - 1):
        break
      for k in range(j + 1, len(list_to_reduce)):
        element_or_false = f(list_to_reduce[j],list_to_reduce[k])
        if element_or_false:
          # We remove the merged elements and append the new one
          del list_to_reduce[k]
          del list_to_reduce[j]
          list_to_reduce.append(element_or_false)
          exit_loops = True
          break

    if len(list_to_reduce) == initial_list_len:
      reducing_is_still_possible = False

 return list_to_reduce
```

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific about what you want to do when there are different merge paths.  For example, {0,1,2}, {1,4}, {3,4} could become {0,1,2,3,4} or {0,1,2}, {1,3,4} depending on the order that the merges occurred.

Comment: @DSM, it doesn't really matter. Any solution is considered correct as long as it's not possible to merge anymore.

Comment: {0,1,2}, {3,4}, {0,1,2,3} is why you cannot do it "efficiently" - e.g. with reduce.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to write it as a reduce because the operator (the reduce operation, which must be a function from two lists of sets to a list of sets) is not associative: "mergeable" sets could be separated by a totally different set. If you have your inputs ordered (i.e. sets with the most common elements are always adjacent), I think you can, but it is a hard requirement. Actually I think it is not solvable in any efficient manner unless the sets are ordered in some way.